# Which microphones are the best to use with hark?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are planning to use hark and are curious about any advice anyone would have relative to choosing the correct microphone array.
Some of them come with usb interfaces, some with jack. Some have 2 microphones, some up to 8.

In your experience(s), what would be the best choice to use on a robot with a standard laptop onboard?

Thanks in advance

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9742/which-microphones-are-the-best-to-use-with-hark?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From Kazuhiro Nakadai:

> Thank you for your interest in HARK.
> Usually, we are using an 8 ch circular microphone array
> around the top of the humanoid's head.
> In this case, the most important thing is that sounds from all channels
> should be recorded synchronously.
> One of the easiest choices is to use RME hammerfall series which support
> multi-channel synchronous A/D conversion.
> We use RASP series developed by System-in-Frontier Inc, which supports HARK
> originally, and differential type of MEMS microphone is available for this device,
> but it is a little bit expensive (RASP series costs 8,000 USD, MEMS microphone costs 100 USD for each.)HARK will support 2-microphone processing (binaural) soon, but the performance will be poor compared to 8ch microphone array.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you should repeat this question on the HARK mailing list also:
HARK-support [at] kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1